# How to drag and drop items between 2 columns using react-beautiful-dnd and material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Still new coding.
I want to drag and drop things between 2 columns(From Morning to Night, vice-versa) using React JS, Material UI, and react-beautiful-dnd.

I manage to drag and drop things but on their own column only, I can't seem to make it work. How can I achieve this?

Here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-3s67c

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You need to follow the documentation, Material-UI is not a problem to do that.

You need to follow the lesson from the library: https://egghead.io/lessons/react-conditionally-allow-movement-using-react-beautiful-dnd-draggable-and-droppable-props

I'll not do your jobs, but juste follow the doc and the exemples.

https://react-beautiful-dnd.netlify.app/?path=/story/board--simple

Comment: I didn't saw that tutorial.
 I just followed the tutorial on youtube
Thank you,